# Octave crashes when printing a plot

Tags: plot, save, octave

**Solution**: As suggested by user Andy in the comments, an update to the newest version of Octave (at the moment: octave-4.0.1-rc4) fixed the problem and the plot could be saved as PNG.

---

I have a large-ish amount of data that I plot in Octave. But when I try to save the image, the program crashes without any explanation or real error message. My Octave is version 4.0 and it's running on Win 8.1, the `graphics_toolkit` is *qt*.

Saving smaller amounts of data has worked so far, but somehow I seem to have reached a size where the plot can be drawn but not saved.

First, I load the data from several files listed in the vector `inputs`:

```
data = [];
for i = 1:length(inputs)
  data = [data; load(inputs{i})];
endfor
```

The result is a 955.524 x 7 matrix containing numbers. Loading alone takes a while on my system (several minutes), but eventually succeeds. I then proceed to plot the data:

```
hold on;
for j = 1:length(data(1,:))
  curenntColumn = normalize(data(:,j)); % make sure all data is in the same range
  plot(1:length(curenntColumn), curenntColumn, colours{j}); % plot column with distinct colour
endfor
hold off;
```

This results in a plot being drawn as Figure 1 that shows all 955.524 entries of each of the seven columns correctly in a distinct colour. If the program ends here, it exits properly. However, if I add

```
print("data.png");
```

Octave will keep running after opening the plot window and eventually crash with a simple "program does not work anymore" error message. The same happens if I try to save manually from the File->Save menu (which offers saving as PDF). Even just touching and moving the plot window takes a few seconds.

I tried using *gnuplot* and *fltk* as `graphics_toolkit`, but the latter does not even open a plot window, and the former seems to be broken (crashes on the attempt of plotting even simple data like `plot(1:10,1:10);`).

Now, I could screenshot the plot and try to work with that, but I'd really rather have it be saved automatically. Also, I find it weird that displaying the curves is possible, but not saving said display. As it works for smaller amounts of data, maybe I just need to somehow allocate more resources to Octave?

Comment: Does it really crash (for example segmentation fault) or is it just very slow / appears to be non-responsive? On windows it could take up to minutes to create the fontcache for the first time. Do you see an error message or that Octave caused a problem and needs to be closed?

Comment: @Andy, It does crash, there is a default Windows error alert (program does not work anymore) and Octave is shut down. Loading the data and displaying the graph both take quite a while but are executed eventually - if I stop there, everything is fine and Octave keeps working. It's the actual saving with `print` that leads to the crash.

Comment: Okay, Octave should never crash. Can you create a comple example which reliably triggers the crash on your system and file a bugreport here: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave
Is it only with hold on/ hold off?

Comment: @Andy, Thanks for your help! I took out hold on/holf off, and now the function does not crash anymore, saves the latest plot and exits as it should, printing the error message "GL2PS info: OpenGL feedback buffer overflow" 13 times. 
Putting the lines back in leads to a crash as before. Should I still file a bug report? 
It is an external (Windows) error named "octave-gui.exe" telling me that octave-gui.exe does not work anymore and is closed due to a problem.

Comment: There was a problem with big prints: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=46417 You may try the 4.0.1-rc4-installer from ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/octave/ and see if it's solved there.

Comment: Thanks again! Updating fixed it. I get even more "GL2PS info" warnings than before now but eventually the plot is saved as a PNG with the new version.

Comment: The gl2ps feedback buffer overflow is really just a informational message which should tell you, that you are printing more primitives (mostly lines) than would fit into the buffer and another one needs to be filled. Btw, you may consider downsampling your data before printing.

Answer (score 0):

It (4.2.2 version) crashes with my Linux Mint. just a simple graph, and it crashed two times in a row. I am going back to R.  I had my hopes up as I wanted to review the Numerical Analysis Using Matlab text.

Wait, come to think of it, the Studio Version of R crashes when I try to use it but not when I run the same program from the command line, so I will go back (one more time) and try to run a plot totally from the command line. The Linux Mint requires a 2 CPU 64 bit, and I just have the 64 bit single CPU.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).