# Octave returns "Octave GUI has stopped working" error when printing a plot with a large number of points

Tags: printing, time-series, octave, figure

I am using GNU Octave (v4.0.2) under Windows 10 to plot large time series comprising more than 5,000,000 points.
The time series are created by merging and decimating data from individual mat files using a "for" loop:

```
dec1=5; %decimation factor for stages 1 and 2
dec2=2; %decimation factor for stage 3
files=dir('*.mat');
nof=size(files,1);
ts=[];
for k=1:nof
  temp=load(files(k).name);
  dectemp=decimate(decimate(decimate(temp.data,dec1,5),dec1,5),dec2,5);
  ts=[ts dectemp];
end
```

Octave has no problem plotting the time series, but crashes down if I am trying to print out the current figure to a file. For instance, trying to print the figure to a png file:

```
 plot(ts); print('test.png');
```

yields the following message: "Octave GUI has stopped working". 
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014056/octave-crashes-when-printing-a-plot), "big prints" were a known problem with older versions of Octave, but it seems v4.0.1. had this issue fixed. Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a way to fix it other than decimating the time series to reduce the overall number of points?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've no problem plotting and printing 5e6 points. You may switch to `graphics_toolkit gnuplot` and see id this works for you or try the CLI. I'm not sure why Windoze thinks the GUI has stopped working (which isn't a "crash" as stated in the topic)

Comment: Using gnuplot as the graphics toolkit did the trick. Many thanks for your answer, Andy! And sorry for mistaking the "Octave GUI has stopped working" error for a crash; I have edited my post to reflect your comment. Thanks again!